# Django, Ionic, $http and a empty response

Tags: android, angularjs, django, ionic-framework

I have a django setup with a csrf view used to set the csrf token to the requester cookies like this:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def csrf_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('', content_type="text/plain")
```

I have djangoc-cors-headers and CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL set to True but, from the android emulator, when I send a get request to it, using $http.get, the response is a error, where data is null and status is 0. Am I missing something?

The angular service looks like this:

```
.factory('CSRF', function ($q, $cookies, $http) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            var q = $q.defer();
            $http.get(csrfEndpoint, {
                withCredentials: true,
                responseType: "text",
                transformResponse: undefined
            })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    q.resolve($cookies['csrftoken']);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log('data: ' + data);  // data is null
                    console.log('status: ' + status);  // status is 0
                    console.log('headers: ' + dictToString(headers()));
                    console.log('config: ' + dictToString(config));
                })
            ;
            return q.promise;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Testing in the android emulator

Answer (score 0):

The problem was of missing configuration. This configuration, actually:

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the cordova version first

```
cordova -v
```

if the version is  >4.3

try adding

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and then add

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

to your config.xml file